# How to transfer data from android device using MTP and having the ext2/3/4 file format to computer on Windows XP

Tags: usb-connection-mode, mtp

I'm trying to learn. I have an android tablet from Kocaso. Apparently to transfer files from my computer to the tablet you need to use MTP.

This seems to imply that I need something for Windows XP to detect the file format ext/2/3/4 of the device so I can transfer stuff like a good old usb key.

So what do I need exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the reasons [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) was introduced for: independency of the file system format used "behind it". You can compare it to using "standard SQL" to retrieve data from a database via an [ODBC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC) driver: your application does not need to know whether there's a MySQL, Oracle, PostGreSQL, or whatever database behind it. As long as it sticks to standard SQL commands, it simply works.

Similar issue with *MTP*. Other than with using [UMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class), your computer doesn't access the [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) directly, but uses a kind of "command layer". On the Android device, *MTP* then plays the role of our above *ODBC* driver, translating everything to the underlying file system.

So as long as your computer knows how to deal with *MTP*, you don't have to even *think* about what file system is used. It should simply work.

But on the other hand, *MTP* has proven tricky sometimes: it requires extra drivers on Windows, and doesn't work out of the box on MacOS or Linux systems (also extra installs and adjustments required here). So there are alternatives you might wish to take a look at for file transfer, such as using apps like [Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/airdroid/com.sand.airdroid), [FTPServer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/FTPServer/lutey.FTPServer), [DavDrive](http://www.appbrain.com/app/DavDrive-Lite/de.fun2code.android.lite.webdrive), or similar.

Comment: This reads as chinesse language to me hahaha , all i know is i cant transfer files to my android device like a good old usb key and theres no simple way around it!

Comment: OK, so let me put it into simple terms: Using MTP, you don't need to care about the underlying file system, the "driver" on the device will deal with that. And even if your OS would understand the underlying file system, the device wouldn't give it direct access with MTP.

Comment: Why did they make this so much more complicated usb keys NTFS file format wasnt good enough jeez.

Comment: I wasted my time understanding the interface of the Wifi transfer app, then tried and payed for the pro version which ironicly does not work, hope those programs you recommanded arent a waste of my time.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: At least they are all available for free. Everything else is quite subjective. So if they solved your issue, please don't forget to "accept" the answer by ticking the check-mark next to it :) Besides: Android never used NTFS (that's a Windows-specific file system) but rather FAT for the cards. And yes, FAT has a bunch of restrictions. I only wish they'd left the choice to the user, and not force MTP on us: though I see its advantages, it doesn't come without trouble.

Comment: Airdroid seems to be read only, cant tranfer files with that. DavDrive and ftp server, oh boy, so now i have to learn how to use FTP from scratch....seems time consuming.Got a link to a complete tutorial?     For future referance if you get a Kocaso tablet and dont have windows 7 or 8 and/or extra money to get a micro sd card, your basically screwing yourself over, no simple way to transfer files to these android device!

Comment: Take a look at [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), which is a graphical FTP frontend. Works like any file manager you might be used to, so no need to "learn FTP commands" (though it doesn't hurt doing so I've heard ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11570/discussion-between-paradebor-and-izzy)

Answer (score 0):

People who designed MTP and those file formats had in mind that in the future, it woudnt be cheapsakes like me with a android device.i mean windows XP and no sd card im a cheapsake indeed.

Answer to my question is using the wifi transfer app from the playstore.
Then using this method refered here [How can I split files on the computer and then assemble them on android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/57273/36153). 
Now i will be able to transfer whatever i want on my android Kocaso tablet.