# How can I split files on the computer and then assemble them on android device?

Tags: file-transfer, mtp

Would be a simple way to bypass the MTP protocol crap to transfer files to my android tablet. There must be app out there that I can split files in pieces on computer and then reassemble on android device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How would that allow you to bypass MTP? What is the actual problem you're attempting to solve?

Comment: Is there a file size limit for MTP? I never used that protocol (my xfers go either via WiFi or via adbfs). I could imagine paradebor wants to transfer e.g. "large video files", and MTP might have trouble coping with them. Just a raw guess.

Comment: @Izzy: Not that I'm aware of. I routinely move files that are hundreds of megabytes in size (CWM backups, ROMs, etc). If there is a limit (skeptical), it would have to be fairly high.

Comment: Im just a regular guy on windows xp with a cheap Kocaso tablet with no SD card trying to transfer stuff on it.This sounds much easier then learning to use FTP out of the blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to transfer the split files from your pc to your android device, which most probably will, you can use [**this**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.joa.zipperplus7) app to join the files.

Also make sure you split the file using 7zip on your pc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Heck yes, exactly what i need, thank you! and for people asking, wifi transfer app works but trial version has a size limit but premium version does not work for some reason.

Comment: This was very simple and quick and it works!Thanks again a million!

Comment: Glad that helped. Consider voting the answer